# Monero Gui syncing... is this supposed to take this long?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

So i just bought some Monero and tried to put in the Monero wallet. The first blocks were kind of fast but now its taking a ridiculous amount of time.
The code below was ran for like 2m. I still have 70 blocks to run, this will take an absurd amount of time. Am i the only one who is facing this problem?

```
SYNCHRONIZATION started
    2018-01-03 13:24:30.645 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403220/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:24:48.237 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403240/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:25:10.017 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403260/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:25:36.846 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403280/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:26:00.985 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403300/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:26:28.593 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403320/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:26:48.702 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403340/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:27:21.921 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403360/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:27:52.981 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403380/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:28:29.171 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403400/1479070[0m
    2018-01-03 13:28:59.711 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1154    [1;33m[94.140.116.213:18080 OUT]  Synced 1403420/1479070[0m
```

Comment: I could be wrong - just noticed - does P2P6 mean you are using IPv6? .. maybe you can force IPv4 and have a better result?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't alone and it's one of the reasons (imo) that Monero isn't more largely adopted. Sync'ing the blockchain when spinning up a node takes a full day - which is simply untenable.

Comment: at the rythim this is atm it will take me 1 week. oh well...

Comment: Yeah, on more than one occasion it caused me to not spin up a monero node. The day I did it, I just so happened to start the sync and had to go out. Brutal.